# Permission to save a file in Python

Tags: python, image, file, permissions

This code

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save(r'D:/MyFilesForProject/Network/screen.jpg')
```

cause this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/PycharmProjects/2.7NetworkExersice/Screenshot.py", line 4, in 
<module>
im.save(r'D:\MyFilesForProject\Network\screen.jpg')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1676, in save
fp = builtins.open(fp, "wb")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'D:\\MyFilesForProject\\Network\\screen.jpg'
```

I tried to find a solution in the whole internet and I did not find anything working. In order to avoid repetitive advice: yes, I allowed reading and writing the folder in the properties and tried to save it in another place. I really hope for your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is r in .save() method?

Comment: This code works fine for me.. The problem it seems is that Python does not have the permission to write the file to D:\.. check that python has permission to write to that location..

Comment: @HarshPatel The `r` specifies that this is a ***r**aw string*, so backslashes won't have to be escaped.

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with builtins usage but fp= ... (fp..) seems a bit awkward to me ...

Comment: @A.Joly That code is part of `PIL` library, it's nothing to do with OP's code.

Comment: I think it is a problem with your file system permissions. Can you create a file at the location?
An other thing is that you should use ``os.path.join`` to access the directory. Doing so will prevent you from escaping the backslashes manually.

Comment: @johnashu yes i can create a file in that directory.

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your code, changed it to "D:\" and it saved the file no problem..

Comment: @JensHöpken i checked my permissions for this disk and directory - all allowed

Comment: @johnashu dont work even so.

Comment: try to run python as an Admin
runas.exe /user:administrator "C:\Python34\python.exe myscript.py"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THere is a problem with Python having Permission to write to that drive.

Try to run Python as an Admin:

From commandline:

```
runas.exe /user:administrator "C:\Python27\python.exe Screenshot.py"
```

I managed to replicate your error by attempting to save to folder that did not have write permissions.

This is how I fixed the error:

1. Right click on the folder you wish to save to.
2. Click `properties` at the bottom of the list
3. Go to the `security` tab
4. Click the `Edit` button next to `To change permissions, click Edit`
5. make sure the `write` section has a tick in the `Allow` column for the user you are logged in as. If this is not a private folder or a security risk you can allow for `everyone`

One other thing I noted was I had the error from the updated fix

```
 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1725, in save
fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
```

note the `w+b` whereas in your traceback you have `wb`

This could be due to using an outdated version of PIL..

Try uninstalling PIL via PIP and then reinstalling the latest version with

```
pip install pil
```

One other difference is that I ran this on Python 3.6 not 2.7 like yourself.

Comment: ok, i entered this code to cmd and the console ask me for admin password, but dont give me to type it. ok, i writed a password for my windows account and copy this in command line - error. Same with pincode to computer. Tryed to run a cmd as admin - even so he ask for password.  but im dont plan this  evrytime to runt this script by cmd. this only part of code, the last part that dont work. maybe u have any solutions?

Comment: If you can run the file ok as admin then you know there is a problem with the permissions. It's very strange that it is not working for you but the code is fine and the error is stating a permissions error.

Comment: yeah, i think so too, but i cant to solve it. What i must do to solve this? Rtinstall PyCharm? Reinstall Python? Reinstall WIndows? To buy a new computer or just to start a make code on Java?